What is the relationship between the magnetic flux density produced and the current flowing through an electromagnet?
I wrapped 10m of 1.5mm gauge around a 20cm roofing nail and am aiming to find the relationship between the magnetic flux density (magnetic field strenghth) produced by the electromagnet and the current that flows through the wire. From research I assumed it was a directly proportional relationship but after collecting my data it seems to be proportional but not directly. I want tpo clarify whether its's supposed to be directly related and theres an issue with my experiemnt or if the relationship isnt directly proportional.

Through the Biot-Savart law, if the current is uniform, then $|\vec{B}|\propto I$. How are you measuring the magnetic field?
